# expressing a grep like algorithm in mapreduce terms for a very long list of keywords

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am having trouble expressing an algorightm in mapreduce terms.

I have two big input text files: Let's call the first file "R" and the 
second one "P". R is typically much bigger than P, but both are big.

In a non-mapreduce approach, the contents of P would be loaded into
memory (hashed) and then we would start iterating over all the lines
in R. The lines in R are just strings, and we want to 
check if any of the substrings in R match any string in P.

The problem is very similar to grepping words in a bigfile, the issue
is that the list of words is very large so you cannot hardcode them 
in your map routine.

The problem I am encountering is that I don't know how to ensure that 
all the splits of the P file end up in a map job per each split of the R file.
So, assuming these splits:

```
R = R1, R2, R3;
P = P1, P2
```

The 6 map jobs have to contain these splits:

```
(R1, P1) (R1, P2);
(R2, P1) (R2, P2);
(R3, P1) (R3, P2);
```

How would you express this problem in mapreduce terms?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent some time working on this and I have come up with a couple of 
solutions. The first one is based on hadoop streaming and the second one uses
native java.

For the first solution I use an interesting feature from ruby. If you add
the keyword `__END__` at the end of your code, all the text after that will 
be exposed by the interpreter via the global variable DATA. This variable 
is a File object. Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.rb
puts DATA.read

__END__
Hello World!
$ ruby /tmp/foo.rb
Hello World!
```

We will use the file R as a input (It will be distributed across the HDFS filesytem).
We iterate over the P file and after traversing a certain number of lines, 
we add those at the end of our mapper script. Then, we submit the job to the 
hadoop cluster. We keep iterating over the contents of P until we have 
consumed all the lines. Multiple jobs will be sent to the cluster based on 
the number of lines per job and the size of P.

That's a fine approach that I have implemented and it works quite well. I 
don't find particularly elegant though. We can do better by writing a native
mapreduce app in java.

When using a native java app, we have a full access to the hadoop HDFS API. 
That means we can read the contents of a file from our code. That's something
I don't think it is available when streaming.

We follow an approach similar to the streaming method, but once we have 
traversed a certain number of lines, we send those to the hadoop cluster instead
of append it to the code. We can do that within the code that schedules 
our jobs.

Then, it is a matter of running as many jobs as the number of splits that 
we have for P. All the mappers in a particular job will load a certain split
and will use it to compute the splits of R.

Answer (score 0):

Nice problem.

One quick way I can think of is to split the P file into multiple files and run multiple MR jobs with each split of the P file and the complete R file as input.

Comment: Sorry.. added the last comment by mistake I meant to write this: How do you split P in such a way that hadoop doesn't split further them when running the MR jobs? Of course I could add the P data within the map's code.

Comment: If the size of each P split is less than the HDFS block size, then the complete P split will be stored in a single HDFS block. But, it shouldn't matter if the file is split into multiple HDFS blocks or not, since logically it's still one file from a user perspective.

I was thinking of a map only job, the map function will be invoked for the R file and the P split file is read in the map file from HDFS and a comparison is done.

A custom partitioner can also be written instead of the above approach. It is a bit complex and the pros/cons have to be evaluated for this approach.